# how to post form data and upload image at the same time in asp.net webapi

Tags: asp.net-web-api, image-uploading

I'm trying to perform something which is fairly common. I want to have a POST method that will receive form data as well as one (or more) image(s).

I thought that the signature should look like the following:

```
[HttpPost]
public void PostNewPost([FromBody] __PostModel PostValues, HttpPostedFileBase PostImage)
{

}
```

So that the form data will be contained in PostValues and the image is received into PostImage.

However I get the infamous

> Can't bind multiple parameters ('PostValues' and 'PostImage') to the
>   request's content.

error message.

Can anyone explain how it is done?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to override the HttpParameterBinding since Web API expects you to use Model Binding (mapping parameters to **a** strongly typed object) and not to several single parameters.

To implement overrides for HttpParameterBinding please check this post, http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Sep/11/Passing-multiple-simple-POST-Values-to-ASPNET-Web-API